# Symfony2 project - app_dev.php works but app.php has redirect loop on just specific page

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I'm not entirely sure what is happening as it's the first time I've encountered this kind of problem, but for some reason, one particular page in my Symfony2 project has a redirect loop on app.php but when on app_dev.php, it's fine.

The page is called /files and the routing for this page is as follows:

```
app_files_table:
    path: /files
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:File:list }
```

The controller method for this page is pretty simple:

```
public function listAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $documents_repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Documents');
    $documents = $documents_repo->findAll();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:tables:files.html.twig', array(
        'files' => $documents
    ));
}
```

The twig template is just a standard layout which matches all my other pages (extending my base file which is the header) with the following code in the main body:

```
{% if files is not empty %}
{% for file in files %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ file.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ file.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ file.displayName }}</td>
        <td>{{ file.product.model }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ file_path }}/{{- file.name -}}" target="_blank" download><i class="fa fa-download"> </i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger file-delete" data-confirm-title="Are you sure?" data-confirm-message="You will not be able to undo this action." href="javascript:deleteFile({{ file.id }});" id="delete_file_{{ file.id }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove File"><i class="fa fa-remove"> </i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<tr>
<td colspan="5">There are no files in the database</td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

I have not edited the app.php, app_dev.php nor the .htaccess files - they are as they were when the framework was installed. I have also cleared the cache twice including removing all cache files manually - yet the redirect problem still occurs.

Is this something that others have encountered and managed to solve? Because I am confused as to why it should be happening on this page - in fact, I even tried putting a die() statement in the controller BEFORE the template is rendered, yet the same thing happens so it must be to do with the routing?

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT - result of debug:router

```
_wdt                                ANY        ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar                ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_purge                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/purge
  _profiler_info                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
  _profiler_phpinfo                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results            ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css             ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  _twig_error_test                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  app_dashboard                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /
  app_user_dashboard                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /user-dashboard
  fos_user_security_login             ANY        ANY      ANY    /login
  fos_user_security_check             ANY        ANY      ANY    /login_check
  app_customers_table                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /customers
  app_orders_table                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /orders
  app_projects_table                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /projects
  app_products_table                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /products
  app_files_table                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /documents
  app_users_table                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /users
  app_categories_table                ANY        ANY      ANY    /categories
  app_customer_view                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /customer/{id}/{orderYear}
  app_order_view                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /order/{id}
  app_project_view                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /project/{id}
  app_user_view                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /user/{id}
  app_customer_add                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /customer/add
  app_address_add                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /address/add/{id}
  app_order_add                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /order/add
  app_user_add                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /user/new
  app_stage_add                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /stage/new
  app_category_add                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /category/new
  app_document_add                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /document/new/
  fos_user_registration_register      ANY        ANY      ANY    /new-user
  fos_user_security_logout            ANY        ANY      ANY    /logout
  fos_user_registration_check_email   ANY        ANY      ANY    /check-email
  fos_user_registration_confirm       ANY        ANY      ANY    /confirm/{token}
  fos_user_registration_confirmed     ANY        ANY      ANY    /confirmed
  fos_user_profile_show               ANY        ANY      ANY    /profile
  fos_user_profile_edit               GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /profile-edit
  app_missing_orders_table            ANY        ANY      ANY    /missing-orders
  app_delete_item                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /delete/{type}/{id}
  app_calendar                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /calendar
  app_ajax_call                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /ajax-call/{action}/{data}
  app_customer_search                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /customer-search
  app_customer_get                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /customer-get
  app_product_search                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /product-search
  app_product_search_id               ANY        ANY      ANY    /product-search-by-id
  app_product_get                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /product-get
  app_add_order                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /add-order
  app_print_job_label                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /print-job-label/{id}
  app_claim_task                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /claim-task/{id}
  app_complete_task                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /complete-task/{id}
  app_stages_edit                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /edit-stages
  app_category_edit                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /edit-category/{id}
  app_run_cron_task                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /cron-generate-projects
  remove_trailing_slash               GET        ANY      ANY    /{url}
  fullcalendar_loader                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /fc-load-events
  fos_js_routing_js                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /js/routing.{_format}
```

Comment: Where are you  being re-directed to?

Comment: what do you have in prod.log ?

Comment: It does not redirect anywhere - I get the "The page isn't redirecting properly" error, as if it's trying to get to the right route but is just going back and forth. Pawel - there are no new logs in prod.log for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to rebuild your bootstrap cache, you can do it via composer scripts, since its production you could do:

```
composer install -o --no-dev
```

Or simply

```
composer run-script post-install-cmd
```

You may also consider to remove the entire cache directory and delete the `app/bootstrap.php.cache` file.

If it doesn't work we will need more information, like config files, environments, logs, etc.

Comment: I ran that code then after clearing the cache I get: "Fatal error: Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/eurotubes_crm/app/AppKernel.php on line 31" - even though it is there....plus the redirect loop is still happening. I can include further information in my question, what exactly is it you need?

Comment: Can you post your virtualhost, the environment variables and the last lines of the log? Also check the command debug:router to see if there is anything strange! But seems to me you have a miss configuration somewhere, so you should check all your config files!

Comment: The debug information does not show anything out of the oridinary - but I did notice that in my net panel on my browser I get the status "301 Moved Permanently"? Environment variables are just dev and prod. I'm using XAMPP on port 8888, but it still has the redirect loop on the live server as well.

Comment: I ended up changing the route name from "files" to "documents" and that seemed to fix it. Perhaps it is a reserved word / route in symfony? Or maybe it pertains to a bundle I installed...

Comment: Its not something predefined! Can you show the result of debug:router?

Comment: I have added the results to my question. Though, having it as "documents" is fine anyway